# Conditionally wrap code in a timeout using javascript

Tags: javascript

I have a few lines of code which I want to possibly wrap in a timeout based on a flag. The simple way to do this is:

```
var myCondition = // true or false
if(myCondition){
     setTimeout(function(){
         myVar++;
         myFunction();
         something = somethingElse;
     }, 1000 );
} else {
    myVar++;
    myFunction();
    something = somethingElse;
}
```

Is there a shorter way to achieve this? like using .call in some fashion?

As pointed out in the comments, I know I can just wrap the code in a function:

```
var myWrapperFunction = function(){
    myVar++;
    myFunction();
    something = somethingElse;
}
```

But what I'm looking for is a conditional way to just apply timeout in a manner shorter than above.

Comment: But what I'm looking for is a way to apply a timeout conditionally on a set of code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure why shorter makes it better or easier to understand. Simpliest way to make it shorter it to put the common code into a function and assign it or call it based on the conditional.

```
var fnc = function () { /* common code */};
if (x) { 
    setTimeout(fnc, 1000); 
} else {
    fnc(); 
}
```

or set the timeout to zero

```
var time = x ? 1000 : 0;
setTimeout(fnc, time);
```